# How to change range to run only when there information

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet where I am doing a VlookUP using VBA. The problem is that I extract information, and the amount is always different. I want to find a way to add to the code that will add information until there is no more information to add.

Here is the code that works but only for the cells I put in:

```
Sub vLook()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EODComponents").Range("f5:F200")
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C5,($H$5:$i$34),2,FALSE)"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I need to change that F200 to make it until there is no more information to comapare

Comment: did you try `UsedRange`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `lastRow`:

```
Sub vLook()
Dim lastRow as Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EODComponents")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,6).End(xlUp).Row 

    With .Range("f5:F" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C5,($H$5:$i$34),2,FALSE)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Bruce, it only gives me the value for F5 but not the rest. You think it might be something with Lastrow? @bruceWayne

Comment: @NickNorwood - If you step through it (press `F8`), what does `lastRow` get set to? I'm assuming your Column F has the most data, so am getting the last row number from there.  Oh! Also, since you want to use a formula (relatively, I assume), change the `Vlookup` line to `.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],R5C8:R34C9,2,FALSE)"`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use a `Do while`-loop?

If you put the while statement right, this will continue until the statement becomes `false`, in your case; there is no more information to add.

You can use the `Len()`-function to check the length of the text/value inside a cell, when this is zero you can assume the cell is empty.

More information about this item can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx).

Example:

```
Public Sub Something()
Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

Do While (Len(Cells(i, 1).Text) > 0)
    i = i + 1
Loop

MsgBox "The next row of column 'A' is empty: A" & i

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.